# Submit button in Android webview not working as its default

Tags: php, android, forms, webview, android-webview

I have a form that I want to submit it in Android web view, but my submit button is not working as its default.

I mean it is not redirected to the `submit.php` page! (It just submits data)
What should I do for it to use its default ?

Here is an example form:

```
<form  id="form" method="post" action="submit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
// other elements ...
<input type="file" name="file" />
</form>
```

How can I force it to use its default again?

Comment: Where does it submit to now? Can you attach files? Please first try with some text inputs only.

Comment: @greenapps it submits fine but my problem is when i click submit button id doesnt goes to submit.php page and the form still exists ! and if user click on submit again repetitive data will be stored in database !     i  want it to behaves as normal and goes to submit.php !